# Redis connection to redis.abc.abc failed - write EPIPE

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

Unable to connect to Redis from NodeJS with following error:

```
Redis connection to redis.example.com failed - write EPIPE
```

Using NodeJS version `v0.10.35`
node_redis module `0.12.1` & Redis DB version `3.0.4`

Currently, NodeJS server is processing around 50K requests per minute, every request doing atleast 2 operations in Redis (GET/SET).

It works fine for sometime (around 30 mins) and later it starts throwing the said error.
Any work around?